# Changing the colour of a tab of an accordion panel

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces' accordion panel. Inside the tabs i have forms which are created programmatically. Each form has a submit button. Now I wanted to change the colour of a tab, if the form of this tab has been submitted. So is it possible to change the color of one specific tab and how could I manage to make this work?

I think i have to use different style classes as mentioned here but I'm not quite sure how to use them.

[How to highlight a primefaces tree node from backing bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576418/how-to-highlight-a-primefaces-tree-node-from-backing-bean)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `titleStyleClass` of the `<p:tab>` tag for this. E.g.

```html
<p:accordionPanel>
    <p:tab title="Step 1" titleStyleClass="#{bean.step1Completed ? 'completed' : ''}">
        ...
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Step 2" titleStyleClass="#{bean.step2Completed ? 'completed' : ''}">
        ...
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="Step 3" titleStyleClass="#{bean.step3Completed ? 'completed' : ''}">
        ...
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

This will set the CSS style class of the tab to `completed` whenever the condition returns `true`. You can just specify the desired CSS in the `.completed {}` style class in your own `style.css` file which you put in `/resources` folder and include by `<h:outputStylesheet name="style.css">`.

```css
.completed {
    background: pink;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but not working. firebug shows that the class is overridden by PF classes. I'm using PF 5.2.. any idea?

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, this works well with `background`'s attribute, but not with `color`'s one, why ?

Answer (score -1):

Perfect answer from @BalusC!
Plus if it's not working for you just add !important; in css.

```
.completed {
background: red !important;
}
```

Comment: No, then you should make your selector more specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles

Comment: You're right! I really didn't knok that. Thanks I'm gonna read more about it.